# Make user's name uppercase with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a welcome message for logged in users;

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Welcome, {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</h1>";
?>
```

But it would say something like "Welcome, john smith" rather than "Welcome, John Smith"

I've tried using;

```
<php?
echo ucfirst
?>
```

But that doesn't work because of how PHP_AUTH_USER is formatted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `ucwords` function? `ucwords($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])`

Comment: Got it with ucwords and adding brackets, added answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

```
<?php
echo ucwords ("<h1>Welcome, {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</h1>");
?>
```

Just needed to add brackets.

Comment: What makes you think this code is a "Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet"? There's another button for generic code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP have function called ucwords(). The ucwords() function converts the first character of each word in a string to uppercase.

```
echo ucwords("<h1>Welcome, {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</h1>");
```